# How to apply cookies to a urllib.request() to prevent a redirect to a sign-in?

Tags: javascript, cookies, urllib

I'm trying to make a search function that gets the raw html from the page. The only problem is to access the page it requires cookies with log-in data to be sent when going to the site or else it redirects to a log-in page.

I know this is possible with the urllib library in python, but I'm using the JS urllib package and I can't seem to find the way to do this. By the way, I have downloaded all the cookies I need to get into the site. I know it works because I've cURLed a page with my cookies.txt file and it worked.

(I changed the site link but let's just say that nodejs.org is a site that redirects you unless you have log-in cookies. Also, it is normally a function that has a callback. This is not the problem.)

```
const urllib = require("urllib")
urllib.request("https://nodejs.org/", function (err, data, res) {
    if (err) { throw err }
    data = data.toString()
    callback(data)
})
```

I just get no output upon trying to log what the webpage text is because of the log-in redirect it does. All I want to be able to do is get the webpage's html as a string and return it.